# Maximum number of consecutive trading holidays from a date/calendar table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am trying to find the maximum number of consecutive trading holidays from a Trading date/calendar table. I have a flag `isTradingHoliday = 1` in the `TradingDate` table that denotes the dates which are trading holidays, otherwise `isTradingHoliday = 0`. How to know which date range was the most consecutive trading holidays in that `TradingDate` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can find the first date and the count of days using the difference of row numbers.  The rest is aggregation and filtering:

```
select top (1) with ties min(tradingdate) as startdate,
       max(tradingdate) as enddate
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (order by tradingdate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by isTradingHoliday order by tradingdate) as seqnum_h
      from calendar c
     ) c
where isTradingHoliday = 1
group by isTradingHoliday, (seqnum - seqnum_h)
order by count(*) desc
```